# How to keep UIView to a maximum size in pixels on iPad but at screen size on iPhone

Tags: swift3, uiview, constraints

I have some buttons and labels on a UIView (a main view to give it a name), I want to keep this view to a maximum size on iPhones but on iPads I want to have a size no more than xxx pixels.

I have added some constrains to these buttons and labels, they position and scale well on iPhones, this is because I added to the main view some constrains to keep it 4 pixels on each side from the border. When running on iPads the view scales to the screen size, so I want to limit the size to say 700 x 400 px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 2 more constraints where you set the your UIView to a height of "<= 700" and a width of "<= 400". Make the priority of the constraint 1000. Then change the constraints that set your edges to 4 to priority 990 .

Comment: I also added horizontal and vertical constraints, 990 prority. Works great, thanks!